# Can't make JS plugins work with Rails 5.1 and Yarn

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, yarnpkg, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I'm trying to install [fullpage.js](https://yarnpkg.com/en/package/fullpage.js) plugin in a Rails 5.1 app following  [this guide's](http://blog.michelada.io/whats-new-in-rails-51) advice but haven't been successful. The steps I've followed are:

1. Entered `yarn add fullpage.js` in the command line
2. Checked that the plugin is listed in package.json (the plugin is indeed listed under dependencies as `"fullpage.js": "^2.9.4"`)
3. Declare the plugin in the JS manifest at `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` using `//= require fullpage`

Unfortunately I get an exception when loading the webpage (

> couldn't find file 'fullpage' with type 'application/javascript'

)

I've tried using `//= require fullpage/fullpage` and `//= require fullpage.js` (this last one as I noticed no other dependencies are listed in package.json with their JS extension. 
None of those variations have worked.

Could you help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what was the problem.

It was simply the way I was referencing the asset files in the manifests. To do it correctly I had to go into the node_modules folder (in the root directory) find the folder where fullpage.js was installed and check inside in which folder the js and css file where exactly located.
In this case they happened to be located in `node_modules/fullpage.js/dist/` so I had to reference them in the manifest as following:

```
#the js file
//= require fullpage.js/dist/jquery.fullpage

#the css file
*= require fullpage.js/dist/jquery.fullpage
```

Note that the name of the file I was referencing were "jquery.fullpage.js" and "jquery.fullpage.css" so I'm just leaving the extensions out as usual.